# How to print a line of text from an HTML file

Tags: python, html, regex

My goal is to use RegEx to scan an email for the word "trade" and then print the entire line that it is found on.

I'm having success using RegEx to capture other data from this HTML document (such as the species, weights, prices, etc.), as well as successfully recognizing the word "trade", but I'm failing at printing the entire line it's on. I did try using BeautifulSoup to accomplish this goal but was having a lot more difficulty doing it that way.

[image: Here is the document I believe is in HTML format (correct me if I'm wrong and it's not HTML):]

Ideally I want to capture and print the two lines that the word "trade" is found on. And here is the code I'm using to try to recognize "trade" and print the line it's on:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        email = f.read()
        pattern = re.search(r'\btrade\b',email).group(0)
        match = re.search(r'\btrade\b', email)
        if match:
            for line in email:
                print("TRADE STUFF:",line)
```

Note that I have tried various methods such as `print("TRADE STUFF:", line.splitlines())` as well as `print("TRADE STUF:", line.stripped_strings)` but neither have succeeded.

Thanks for any help.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FW: NEFS 5 Available Fish</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><b>Subject: </b>FW: NEFS 5 Available Fish</td></tr><tr><td><b>From: </b>Claire Fitz-Gerald <claire@capecodfishermen.org></td></tr><tr><td><b>Date: </b>9/5/2014 9:52 AM</td></tr></table><br>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; "><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Wingdings;
    panose-1:5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book";
    panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi";
    panose-1:2 11 7 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle18
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
/* List Definitions */
@list l0
    {mso-list-id:1512259006;
    mso-list-template-ids:-893643712;}
@list l0:level1
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:\F0B7;
    mso-level-tab-stop:.5in;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    mso-ansi-font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:Symbol;}
ol
    {margin-bottom:0in;}
ul
    {margin-bottom:0in;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Apologies for the delay in distributing this listing.&nbsp; It got lost in my inbox.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Please see the below quota listings.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Thanks,<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> NEFS V [mailto:nefsector5@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Monday, September 01, 2014 8:46 PM<br><b>To:</b> mike walsh - 6; NEFS 11 &amp; 12 - Josh Wiersma; NEFS 13 John Haran; NEFS 2 - Dave Leveille; NEFS 3 - Rob Banks; NEFS 6 &amp; 10 Jim Reardon; NEFS 7 &amp; 8 - Linda MaCann; NEFS 9 - Stephanie Rafael-DeMello; paula lynch - 10; Claire Fitz-Gerald; Sector - MCCS; Sector - NCCS; Sector - Sustainable Harvest; tory bramante- 6<br><b>Subject:</b> NEFS 5 Available Fish<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><div><p class=MsoNormal>All,<br>NEFS 5 has the following fish available for lease/trade:<o:p></o:p></p></div><div><ul type=disc><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><strong><span style='font-size:13.5pt'>GB EAST cod: 954 lbs @ $0.83</span></strong><o:p></o:p></li><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><strong><span style='font-size:13.5pt'>GB EAST cod: 1,046 lbs to trade for 1,830 lbs GB WEST cod</span></strong><o:p></o:p></li><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><strong><span style='font-size:13.5pt'>GB blackback: 30,000 lbs @ $0.07</span></strong><o:p></o:p></li><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><strong><span style='font-size:13.5pt'>GOM blackback: 800 lbs @ $0.03</span></strong><o:p></o:p></li><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><strong><span style='font-size:13.5pt'>white hake: 6,322 lbs @ $0.13</span></strong><o:p></o:p></li><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><strong><span style='font-size:13.5pt'>pollock: 22,000 lbs @ $0.015</span></strong><o:p></o:p></li><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><strong><span style='font-size:13.5pt'>redfish: 14,000 lbs @ $0.015</span></strong><o:p></o:p></li><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><strong><span style='font-size:13.5pt'>GB yt: 1,873 lbs @ $1.13</span></strong><o:p></o:p></li><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><strong><span style='font-size:13.5pt'>GB yt: 5,127 lbs to trade for 10,254 lbs SNE yt</span></strong><o:p></o:p></li></ul><div><p class=MsoNormal>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal>-- <o:p></o:p></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></p></div></div><div><p class=MsoNormal>Daniel Salerno, NEFS 5<o:p></o:p></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal>C/O NESTCo.<o:p></o:p></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal>55 State Street<o:p></o:p></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal>Narragansett, RI 02882<o:p></o:p></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal>401-932-0070<o:p></o:p></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal>401-633-6539 (fax)<o:p></o:p></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal><a href="mailto:nefsector5@gmail.com" target="_blank">nefsector5@gmail.com</a><o:p></o:p></p></div><div class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'></body></html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should share the HTML file as well.

Comment: Sorry I always forget to add that in. I'll add it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
   while 1:
      line=f.readline()
      if not line:
         break
      if "trade" in line.lower():
         tags=line.replace('>','<').split('<')
         for tag in tags:
            if "trade" in tag.lower():
               print("TRADE STUFF: ",tag.strip())
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! Can I just ask, for my own sake, how that code works? From my understanding, you're simply searching for the word "trade" and then are you grabbing the tags? Or what is inside the tags?

Comment: For each line in the file:

**1** .replace() is changing all the '>' into '<' meaning that the line will look like this "<someText<<someText<<someText<"

**2** .split() then breaks this up into a list, using the '<' as the separator, meaning each line is now [someText,someText,someText]

We've effectively created a list which holds the contents of each individual tag in the line.

**3** We then loop over the list and if "trade" is one of the items, we print it. 

Because all of the text you want is contained within one tag, it makes sense to do it this way.

Comment: Ohhhhh I gotcha. Wow that was really smart to do, did you just come up with that idea from a lot of experience with HTML?

Comment: I don't know anything about HTML, I just saw that what you needed was between '<>' symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your 'for' loop and your 'if' statement, like so:

```
for line in email:
    if match:
       print("TRADE STUFF: ", line)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my dilemma, sorry I wasn't very clear in explaining it. I can access the entire line, but because it is HTML it prints out the HTML code, so all the tags and everything. I want just the text itself to be printed.